# What type of tree is this? (Coyote Hills)

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

[image]
I found this in [Coyote Hills, Los Angeles, USA](https://www.google.com/maps/place/West+Coyote+Hills/@33.9052916,-117.9644732,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80dd2ae5b78febe1:0xa64129cd944aec8c!8m2!3d33.9052916!4d-117.9622845). Please provide the common name.

Comment: Do you have more close-up images of the twigs? could you find any see any flowers/ seeds etc (such as beneath the tree)? if possible photograph them.

Comment: some sort of  [*Taxodium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxodium)?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Please ensure your post is [formatted correctly](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) as well.

Comment: For species identification questions, [this page](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/are-there-any-guideline-about-species-identification-questions) may help you about what things could help to answer.

Comment: Size: You can probably tell by the fence post; the tree is probably about 3 times normal human height

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is *Schinus molle* (Peruvian pepper)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32724)

Comment: the person don't search a name of this tree? in facht i don't understand why it is not a answer of the question.

Comment: We like to see sources. A random species name doesn't say much.

Comment: which source could answer this question? i see no other possible like i did. and indeed it is not much, but better than not answer the question. we can discus this answer but i don't know the reason to don't give it a try.

Comment: Add a link to wikipedia is enough?